# How do you send responsive emails with Phoenix

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, email, zurb-foundation, phoenix-framework

I am sending basic emails from a Phoenix app, but would like to improve them to be responsive on all devices.
I have tried [Foundation Emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html) but am unable to compile the inline-email when I need to inject model values using .eex syntax

```
<%= model.value >
```

The .eex syntax confuses the compiler. So I'm wondering how everyone else does it with Phoenix?

At moment I don't see how I can use Bootstrap because email clients strip out the style tag, so the styles need to be inline, and I can only find Foundation Emails that compile the css inline.

I could compile inline and then manually go through and add the model references, but is there a better way?

Thanks to anyone that can offer some advice.

Comment: Just a quick comment, are you designing emails for Mobile? Or are you designing emails for people viewing it on their desktop. The reason I ask, because mobile mail clients are not responsive, they shrink the email to fit.

Comment: According to [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/compatibility.html) their responsive emails are mobile compatible, for example, iPhone 5 and 6, but they don't mention the iOS version, so I would want to do some testing, but can't compile as per my question. Considering the quantity of emails that are opened on mobile devices, I was hoping there was some kind of best/recommended practice etc.

Comment: Mobile compatible and "email client on a mobile phone" are two different things.